# Pesquise sobre a função nl2br ou concatene: print "you can eat: $dish"."<br />";

Tags: php

```
   Pesquisei ,e,encontrei essa teoria bem explicadinha aqui nesse site: "https://imasters.com.br/artigo/3296/php/dica-funcao-nl2br-php-no-dreamweaver/?trace=1519021197&source=single".
```

Mas aplicar a teoria bem explicada acima , na prática ,nesse código aqui abaixo , é que são outros 100% ,que eu ainda não sei como fazer ,se o nobre amigo souber ,eu agradeceria ,que colocasse o mesmo ai em LOCO, caso não saiba, fico aguardando ,quem sabe,e pesquisando ao mesmo tempo.
ONDE E COMO DEVO COLOCAR " >>> nl2br<< , Nesse meu código ai abaixo:

3.00,
'Braised Bamboo Fungus');

foreach ($dinner as $dish) {

print "You can eat: $dish\\n";
}   

?>
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Pra ficar funcional como foi colocado nesse outro aqui abaixo : 
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Veja na prática o código acima funcionando (é assim que eu quero que o meu funcione) :

Vamos aos códigos. Suponhamos que você
esteja resgatando esse texto de um banco de dados por exemplo,
então você teria um código assim:

E este resultaria neste exemplo:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit,
minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper sus
velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi Lorem ipsum dolor sit
erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru
dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie conseq
luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla fa

Como você percebeu fica difícil e
sem estímulo a leitura do texto. Para resolvermos utilizamos
a função nl2br assim:

Com a função em uso teremos:

Loren ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit
minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper su
velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit
minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper su
velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

A dicas é simples e a diferença é
nítida e a partir de agora seus textos na web ficarão
mais agradavéis e convidativo para a leitura.

Aqui vai a pergunta simples : Como colocar esse dito cujo "MILACROSO", nesse meu código: ?

$dinner = array('Sweet Corn and Asparagus',
'Lemon Chicken',
'Dried Mulberries' => 3.00,
'Braised Bamboo Fungus');

foreach ($dinner as $dish) {

print "You can eat: $dish\n";
}

?>

Comment: Código pelo amor de jesus.

Comment: Cara, que coisa mais estranha, nunca me deparei com isso, quando altero o <?php ?> para o erro

Comment: O seu código não contém erro de syntax. Oque pode estar gerando o erro é isso [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration72.deprecated.php). O estranho é que você está recebendo o erro mesmo não usando constantes no código. Isso presumindo que você está usando php7.2.

Comment: @fajuchem eu copiei o código e coloquei pra rodar aqui e apresentou o mesmo problema dele, porem, quando eu mudei o <?php ?>, simplesmente reescrevi, acabou o problema

Comment: Dentro das tags php coloque `phpinfo();` e veja qual é a versão do seu php. Comente as outras linhas para não dar erro

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em um character unicode utilizado dentro das tags do php dependendo da IDE ou editor que você usa ele pode ter ficado "invisivel".
O character é esse aqui "<200b>".

Segue uma imagem mostrando o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]